# how do I generate data from an xml file in html

Tags: xml, http, xslt

I have never done xml before but I created something in json that works but my instructor wants to see the same thing in xml.

This is what I have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <element>
      <boxclass>fancybox</boxclass>
      <folder>nu_images</folder>
      <pic>gd_42.jpg</pic>
      <tfolder>nu_images/th/</tfolder>
      <thumbpic>th_gd_42.jpg</thumbpic>
      <title>Rand Poster 1</title>
      <url>http://galnova.com/</url>
   </element>
   <element>
      <boxclass>fancybox</boxclass>
      <folder>nu_images</folder>
      <pic>gd_13.jpg</pic>
      <tfolder>nu_images/th/</tfolder>
      <thumbpic>th_gd_13.jpg</thumbpic>
      <title>Explosive Pixel Design</title>
      <url>http://galnova.com/</url>
   </element>
   <element>
      <boxclass>fancybox</boxclass>
      <folder>nu_images</folder>
      <pic>hubris.jpg</pic>
      <tfolder>nu_images</tfolder>
      <thumbpic>hubris_thumb.jpg</thumbpic>
      <title>Hiding Hubris</title>
      <url>http://galnova.com/</url>
   </element>
   <element>
      <boxclass>fancybox</boxclass>
      <folder>pro_images</folder>
      <pic>m_gcj.jpg</pic>
      <tfolder>pro_images/_th/</tfolder>
      <thumbpic>th_m_gcj.jpg</thumbpic>
      <title>Global Comic Jam Mockup</title>
      <url>http://galnova.com/</url>
   </element>
   <element>
      <boxclass>fancybox</boxclass>
      <folder>A14</folder>
      <pic>fir.jpg</pic>
      <tfolder>A14</tfolder>
      <thumbpic>fir_thumb.jpg</thumbpic>
      <title>Fir-God of Fire</title>
      <url>http://galnova.com/</url>
   </element>
   <element>
      <boxclass>fancybox</boxclass>
      <folder>nu_images</folder>
      <pic>gd_37.jpg</pic>
      <tfolder>nu_images/th/</tfolder>
      <thumbpic>th_gd_37.jpg</thumbpic>
      <title>MoTown Winter Blast Logo</title>
      <url>http://galnova.com/</url>
   </element>
   <element>
      <boxclass>fancybox</boxclass>
      <folder>nu_images</folder>
      <pic>tking.jpg</pic>
      <tfolder>nu_images</tfolder>
      <thumbpic>tking_thumb.jpg</thumbpic>
      <title>Ticking Time Bomb</title>
      <url>http://galnova.com/</url>
   </element>
   <element>
      <boxclass>fancybox</boxclass>
      <folder>pro_images</folder>
      <pic>m_sin.jpg</pic>
      <tfolder>pro_images/_th/</tfolder>
      <thumbpic>th_m_sin.jpg</thumbpic>
      <title>Sins Mockup</title>
      <url>http://galnova.com/</url>
   </element>
   <element>
      <boxclass>fancybox</boxclass>
      <folder>nu_images</folder>
      <pic>gd_25.png</pic>
      <tfolder>nu_images/th/</tfolder>
      <thumbpic>th_gd_25.jpg</thumbpic>
      <title>Ground Zero Logo</title>
      <url>http://galnova.com/</url>
   </element>
   <element>
      <boxclass>fancybox</boxclass>
      <folder>nu_images</folder>
      <pic>gd_43.jpg</pic>
      <tfolder>nu_images/th/</tfolder>
      <thumbpic>th_gd_43.jpg</thumbpic>
      <title>Rand Poster 2</title>
      <url>http://galnova.com/</url>
   </element>
</root>
```

This is my structure of the html page. I tried to use xslt in the html page to generate the data but it is breaking and I don't know why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.galnova.com/2015/xml/index.xml">
<xsl:template match="/">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>KEITH JETER XML SAMPLE</title>

</head>

<body>
<header></header>
<div class="bg_bottom_stretch">
    <div class="bg_top_center">
        <div class="evertin">
        <h2>QUICK GALLERY</h2>
            <div id="gallery">

            <xsl:for-each select="root/element">

            <a class="<xsl:value-of select="boxclass"/>" rel="gallery1" href="<xsl:value-of select="url"/><xsl:value-of select="folder"/>/<xsl:value-of select="pic"/>" title="<xsl:value-of select="title"/>"><img src="<xsl:value-of select="url"/><xsl:value-of select="tfolder"/>/<xsl:value-of select="thumbpic"/>" border="0" alt="<xsl:value-of select="title"/>" title="<xsl:value-of select="title"/>"></a>         
            </xsl:for-each>           
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="2015/css/g15.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help with this will be appreciated. I feel like I am missing a few steps on this one.

Comment: How is it breaking?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: I fixed the one error on the xml page with the double <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: The page isn't actually throwing an error...I don't think. I am attaching a link. http://galnova.com/index-real-xml.html

Comment: Your stylesheet has numerous syntactic issues. You need a tool that will point them out to you. If you don't have one on your computer, try this one: http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your current XSLT: the opening `<html>` tag is missing and the `<meta>` and `<img>` tags are not closing. In addition, the following evaluation for the `<a>` and `<img>` tags won't work:

```
<a class="<xsl:value-of select="boxclass"/>" 
 rel="gallery1" href="<xsl:value-of select="url"/><xsl:value-of select="folder"/>/
 <xsl:value-of select="pic"/>" title="<xsl:value-of select="title"/>">
 <img src="<xsl:value-of select="url"/><xsl:value-of select="tfolder"/>/
 <xsl:value-of select="thumbpic"/>" border="0" alt="<xsl:value-of select="title"/>" 
 title="<xsl:value-of select="title"/>">
</a>
```

Just as example for the `class`: you can evaluate the value of the `boxclass` just like this:

```
<a class="{boxclass}">
```

and for getting the value for `href` concatenate the values of `url`, `folder` and `pic` as follows:

```
href="{concat(url,folder,'/',pic)}"
```

The complete adjusted XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>KEITH JETER XML SAMPLE</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <header></header>
        <div class="bg_bottom_stretch">
          <div class="bg_top_center">
            <div class="evertin">
              <h2>QUICK GALLERY</h2>
              <div id="gallery">
                <xsl:for-each select="root/element">
                 <a class="{boxclass}" rel="gallery1" href="{concat(url,folder,'/',pic)}" title="{title}">
                   <img src="{concat(url,folder,'/',thumbpic)}" border="0" alt="{title}" title="{title}"/>
                 </a>         
                </xsl:for-each>           
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="2015/css/g15.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that this is a version using an external Saxon XSLT-Processor - saved demo version [here](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFA/1). But it should work if you just replace the templates of your current XSLT with the templates provided in this demo and adjust both XML and XSLT according to below explanation on how to get it working locally.

As example how to adjust this to work locally with a browser,  adjust the XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xtest.xslt"?>
<root>
....
```

where xtest.xslt is the name of the XSLT file, and the beginning of the XSLT like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
....
```

and save it next to the XML-file. When you open the XML with e.g. Firefox, the XLST will be applied to the XML file and the result displayed as output.

**Update:** As suggested in the comment, I recommend just to parse the XML using jQuery as using this approach is simpler and your requirement is just to use an XML instead of JSON. I've just adjusted your javascript that parses the JSON like this to work with XML. As you're only using one XML file, I just call the function `loadXml()` without any parameter and load the XML - `input.xml` - which for my testing purposes is just next to the HTML file in this function. So the value of `url` has to be adjusted for your settings. 
Instead of iterating over all JSON elements using a `for` loop, I just store all `element` nodes in `gal`

```
gal = $xml.find('element')
```

and iterate over all these elements using jQuery `each()`

```
$(gal).each(function() { ... }
```

There, the `str` is adjusted to get the values from the XML:

```
str += "<a class=\"" + $(this).find("boxclass").text() + "\" ....
```

**Complete jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXml() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'input.xml',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) { parseXml(xml); }
  });
}

function parseXml(xml) {
  var $xml = $(xml),
      gal = $xml.find('element'),
      str = "";

  $(gal).each(function() {
    str += "<a class=\"" + $(this).find("boxclass").text() + "\" rel=\"gallery1\" href=\"" + $(this).find("url").text() + $(this).find("url").text() + "\/" + $(this).find("pic").text() + "\"" + "title=\"" + $(this).find("title").text() + "\">" + "<img src=\"" + $(this).find("url").text() + $(this).find("tfolder").text() + "\/" + $(this).find("thumbpic").text() + "\"" + "border=\"0\"" + "alt=\"" + $(this).find("title").text() + "\"" + "title=\"" + $(this).find("title").text() + "\"\/>" + "</a>";
  });

   $("#gallery").html(str);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  loadXml();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Just one question. Where is the external xml file being pulled in in that html. That's the only part I don't understand.

Comment: @user3174713 That seems to be a misunderstanding - when you just open the XML file with a browser (tested with Firefox), the XSLT referenced in this XML - in this example: `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xtest.xslt"?>` - will be applied to the XML and the HTML is generated in the browser. If you check the source code of this  generated page, you'll see the XML. If you check the _generated_ source code,  it's the result of the XSL transformation - the HTML.

Comment: I am very confused. I am sorry. I have an html page with xstl in in correct. All I want to do is reference the .xml file and everything should work right? I have no idea how to do that. I tried what you wrote but I think I implemented it wrong. http://galnova.com/index-real-xml.html

Comment: @user3174713 Maybe it's a misunderstanding on _my_ side - I thought you would like to generate an HTML page from an XML file using XSLT in the browser which would work like described: opening the XML file in the browser and having the XSLT file as reference in the XML file. Currently you have an XSLT file saved as HTML that references the XML. As far as I know this won't work. If it's _really_ required to use an XSLT inside an HTML, this could be done using Javascript - check e.g. here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations .

Comment: @user3174713 Additional question - is it only required  to use XML instead of Json and using XSLT is not really required? It could be simpler just to parse the XML using Javascript or jQuery instead of using a Javascript `XSLTProcessor` to  apply an XSLT in an HTML (though this can be done).

Comment: I have a json sample that works fin here matthias http://galnova.com/index-real-json.html My instructor wants me create the exact same thing in xml and it stumped me. I'm looking for the most simple most straightforward method possible.

Comment: @user3174713 Then I recommend just to parse the XML using jQuery - I've just updated my answer with a jQuery approach (tested and works for me). I guess that's what your instructor wanted you to do - parsing an XML using jQuery instead of parsing a JSON. Using XSLT would be a totally different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is occurring because you can have only 1 definition line (the first line)  You have two.  Below is sample code that serializes your data and then deserializes the data.  Remove one.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Root root = new Root() {
                elements = new List<Element>() {
                    new Element(){
                        boxclass = "fancybox",
                        folder = "nu_images",
                        pic = "gd_42.jpg",
                        tfolder = "nu_images",
                        thumpic = "th_gd_42.jpg",
                        title = "Rand Poster 1",
                        url = "http://galnova.com"
                    },
                    new Element(){
                        boxclass = "fancybox",
                        folder = "nu_images",
                        pic = "gd_13.jpg",
                        tfolder = "nu_images",
                        thumpic = "th_gd_13.jpg",
                        title = "Explosive Pixel Design",
                        url = "http://galnova.com"
                    },
                    new Element(){
                        boxclass = "fancybox",
                        folder = "nu_images",
                        pic = "hubris.jpg",
                        tfolder = "nu_images",
                        thumpic = "hubris_thumb.jpg",
                        title = "Hiding Hubris",
                        url = "http://galnova.com"
                    },
                    new Element(){
                        boxclass = "fancybox",
                        folder = "pro_images",
                        pic = "m_gcj.jpg",
                        tfolder = "pro_images/_th/",
                        thumpic = "th_m_gcj.jpg",
                        title = "Global Comic Jam Mockup",
                        url = "http://galnova.com"
                    },
                    new Element(){
                        boxclass = "fancybox",
                        folder = "A14",
                        pic = "fir.jpg",
                        tfolder = "A14",
                        thumpic = "fir_thumb.jpg",
                        title = "Fir-God of Fire",
                        url = "http://galnova.com"
                    },
                    new Element(){
                        boxclass = "fancybox",
                        folder = "nu_images",
                        pic = "gd_37.jpg",
                        tfolder = "nu_images",
                        thumpic = "th_gd_37.jpg",
                        title = "MoTown Winter Blast Logo",
                        url = "http://galnova.com"
                    },
                    new Element(){
                        boxclass = "fancybox",
                        folder = "nu_images",
                        pic = "tking.jpg",
                        tfolder = "nu_images",
                        thumpic = "tking_thumb.jpg",
                        title = "Ticking Time Bomb",
                        url = "http://galnova.com"
                    },
                    new Element(){
                        boxclass = "fancybox",
                        folder = "pro_images",
                        pic = "gd_42.jpg",
                        tfolder = "m_sin.jpg",
                        thumpic = "th_m_sin.jpg",
                        title = "Sins Mockup",
                        url = "http://galnova.com"
                    },
                    new Element(){
                        boxclass = "fancybox",
                        folder = "nu_images",
                        pic = "gd_25.jpg",
                        tfolder = "nu_images",
                        thumpic = "th_gd_25.jpg",
                        title = "Ground Zero Logo",
                        url = "http://galnova.com"
                    },
                    new Element(){
                        boxclass = "fancybox",
                        folder = "nu_images",
                        pic = "gd_43.jpg",
                        tfolder = "nu_images",
                        thumpic = "th_gd_43.jpg",
                        title = "Rand Poster 2",
                        url = "http://galnova.com"
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root ));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Root readData = (Root)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("element")]
        public List<Element> elements {get;set;}
    }
    [XmlRoot("element")]
    public class Element
    {
        [XmlElement("boxclass")]
        public string boxclass {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("folder")]
        public string folder {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("pic")]
        public string pic {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("tfolder")]
        public string tfolder {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("thumpic")]
        public string thumpic {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("title")]
        public string title {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("url")]
        public string url {get;set;}
    }
}
​
```

Comment: What is this in connection to?

Comment: The teacher wants XML.  The code above fully parses the XML into classes.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I got it to work on the server thanks to you all!