# XML Outputs in Visual C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, xml-serialization

I used this method (serialization) to create data (skills) into a combo-box. I can select a player, a skill rate it and then save a comment and it writes to an xml skill.

I am hoping to be able to do this for multiple combo-boxes (one for each skill) or, be able to choose a different skill in 1 combo-box, rate it and write it until all skills have a rating and are written.

Currently, I can only save 1 skills to 1 user. I have 12 skills and I'd like to rate each one and save it to an XML document.

If I do it for 1 person, 1 skill and 1 rating it works. But if I change person, change skill and rate the skill, it overwrites the existing XML document.

So how can I easily successfully write Multiple XML's (or multiple players) with multiple skills and ratings?

1 document could = Player Name, 12 skills aka (Standard, pop, push etc) (its football skills), with a rating for each of the 12 skills?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my full answer in following post : [how do I generate data from an xml file in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722911/how-do-i-generate-data-from-an-xml-file-in-html/29723319#29723319).  The class below uses a List to create an array of elements.

```css
[XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("element")]
        public List<Element> elements {get;set;}
    }
```